# Usage of Ajax form

Tags: ajax, forms, cakephp

I am an average newbie to CakePHP. While reading cookbook found Ajax form and its submission. But it lacks more details.

> What are the main difference between ajax form and a normal form or What are the more specific cases we need to use Ajax form over normal form?

An example will be appreciated

Thanks....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [properly implemented](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) Ajax form is exactly the same as a regular form, except that if JavaScript is enabled a submit handler will be bound to it that will prevent the normal submission of the form and send the data using the [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xmlhttprequest) object. The response will then be processed by JavaScript in the current page instead of by loading an entirely new page.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't necessarily a CakePHP question, it's understanding what AJAX is.

AJAX in layman's terms is basically submitting data to a website without reloading the current page. If this is the sort of feature you want, you'll need to look into the `RequestHandler` component and the `JsHelper` in the CakePHP book for the version you are using.